# Regex to match a particular character within a pair of tags?

Tags: regex

For example this `<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>`will match the whole line of text enclosed by any pair of tags. But how do I match some particular character from that line? For example, the straight single quotation mark or apostrophe ( ' )?

**UPDATE**

Here are some examples:

1) to match the single quotation mark or apostrophe ( ' )

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu'r adipisicing elit.</p>
```

2) to match the double quotation mark in the beginning of the word *adipisicing* (the word is just an example it could be any word or a single letter).

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur "adipisicing" elit.</p>
```

3) to match the double quotation mark in the end of the word *adipisicing* (the word is just an example it could be any word or a single letter).

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur "adipisicing" elit.</p>
```

The expression should not match anything outside any pair of tags. In the above examples it's a paragraph, but it could be anything: heading, span, font tags etc.

**UPDATE#2**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

<span>hello, the world's ugliest dog</span><br>

<span>hello "world"</span><br>

<span>hello 'world'</span>

<p class="someclassname">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt "u" labore et dolore's magna aliqua.
</p>
<p class="someclassname">
    Lorem 'ipsum' dolor sit amet, consectetur's adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor "incididunt" ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you mean?

Comment: Please be clear about your question and explain it with real time example

Comment: You should really consider using an HTML parser here.  It is going to be difficult to achieve such a narrow replacement using regex alone.

Comment: What do you want to match those single or double quotes for? Is it to remove them? Or just to match the content of a tag that has them?

Comment: @LukStorms I think he wants to do a selective replacement of certain characters appearing inside HTML tags, using Notepad++.

Comment: @LukStorms I think he wants to do a selective replacement of certain characters appearing inside HTML tags, using Notepad++.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thank you for your help, Tim. If an HTML parser is what I need here then I guess I should learn a bit about that thing first, because for now I have no idea what that is. Thank you one more time.

Comment: @LukStorms I want to replace all single or double straight quotation marks and apostrophes within any pair of tags in html document with curly equivalents. Like this: "Lorem" -> “Lorem”, Lorem's -> Lorem’s

Comment: @AhuLee don't use regex to parse HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace those single and double quotation marks.

This will work in Notepad++

**Find what** :

```
<([a-zA-Z]\w*).*?>[^'"]+?\K(?:(['])((\w+)\2)?|(["])((\w+)\5)?)(?=[^<]*<\/\1>)
```

**Replace with** :

```
(?{2}’)(?{3}$4’)(?{5}“)(?{6}$7”)
```

**Search mode :** Regular expression (with `. matches newline` checked)

Note: Works with the Replace All, but somehow doesn't work with the single replace in my version of Notepad++.
And you might have to push that **Replace All** button **a few times** if there is more then 1 word surrounded by quotes in 1 tag content.

To get an idea what happens there, see the [test here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4YJHOv/3)

The regex uses lazy matching `.*?` to the first single or double quote character, while the second occurence of the double qoute is optional.
The `\K` makes sure the first part doesn't get consumed.
As does the positive lookahead `(?=` for the last part.

As for the replace.
Since Notepad++ uses the regex engine from Boost, conditional replacements can be used here.

Comment: I have already answered to you on that question when you asked me "what do you want to match those single or double quotes for?" I copy/paste it here one more time for the sake of convenience: I want to replace all single or double straight quotation marks and apostrophes within any pair of tags in html document with curly equivalents. Like this: "Lorem" -> “Lorem”, Lorem's -> Lorem’s

Comment: thank you very much for trying to help. Unfortunately your expression does not replace anything in my document. I'll add code of the example document to my question for you to see. See under UPDATE#2

Comment: But if you don't know how to make the replacement work or simply don't want to bother with it any further please say so in a comment and I'll accept your current answer since my initial question was how to match (and not to replace) a particular character within a pair of tags.

Comment: @AhuLee  Oddly enough, in Notepad++ it doesn't seem to work with the single replace O_O. But it does work if you use the Replace All. And you have to turn that the `. matches newline` on. (your new example has multilines in the content). But with more then 1 occurence of quotes in a contect, you'll have to push that Replace All button a few times to get em all.

Comment: @AhuLee A question. I notice in that new example that you also have words surrounded by single qoutes. F.e. `'world'`  So does that second quote also need replacement?

Comment: ideally yes, but now i think that the more logical (and probably simplest) approach would be to conform the existing quotation marks to one or another standard first (i.e. single or double quotes). And only then replace them to curly variants. As for your last RegEx it does change the quotation marks within the second p tag as well, which is not needed. Also, there are errors with single quotations, but as I said previously it is probably better to replace them with double quotes first. So, that is a matter for another question I guess. Thank you!

Comment: @AhuLee It's fine, I treat this more as a puzzle site anyway. But one with the type of puzzles where the experience is actually usefull in real life.  The answer has been updated again.

Comment: @AhuLee Btw, you are aware that the [XML conform way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) to replace those quotes would be to replace them with `&apos;` or `&quot;`

Comment: I prefer not to use entity references and to see the text "as is". As I know there's no real difference and hence a reason in using them.  Or do you simply mean there's some point in using them just temporarily in order to distinguish between quotation marks of the code and of the actual text? But since the straight quotes and apostrophes pretty much almost always is the initial sate of the text you begin to work with you still need to find/replace (convert) them to the entity references somehow, Or is there some special tool/plugin in/for Notepad++ that does just that?

Comment: @AhuLee There's a `Tidy2` plugin you could try? The `XML Tools` plugin doesn't seem to be a good fit for stuff like this.

Comment: I know there's Tidy2. I have been using this pluging for years. But what about the config? What settings should I use in order to replace quotes and apostrophes within any pair of tags with entity references using Tidy2?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. I never use it. But from what I find online you can't choose what with `quote-marks: yes` is used for the replacement. So it would just make it easier to write a regex to replace the `&quot;` and `&#39;` afterwards.